# doesn't velocity support &acute?

Tags: java, templates, velocity

I have the following text to be displayed:
SAVING:BAHCO1/4 ´ ´ SOCKETS&ACC.FROM CENDAI

however, when I escape the  acute signs with ampersand+acute, I become the following error:
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 164; columnNumber: 41; The entity "acute" was referenced, but not declared.
    ... 15 more

I have no problem with ampersand plus amp.

Anybody had the following problem? how can I work around it?

Answer (score 1):

(More of a comment but I cannot still make comments.)

Tried putting in .vtl file `&´` and `´` but cannot reproduce the error.
what velocity version do you use?
please give a String which produces the error when included in .vtl file.
Also what exactly you mean by *"I have no problem with ampersand plus amp."* ?

Comment: well... I worked around the problem by replacing the sign with its unicode code which worked...